# Stimulating VS Various, Numerous

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is the use of STIMULATING appropriate in the following sentence or can I use VARIOUS/NUMEROUS instead? If yes, how would it change the meaning of the sentence?

**There are stimulating factors because of which people need to be careful about their education.**

I am trying to say "many factors" without the use of word MANY. And does the use of *stimulating* change the whole meaning of sentence?

Comment: "because of which" is awkward. "There are many reasons why people need to be careful about their education" would be better.

Comment: can I use "due to" instead of "because"?

Comment: You mean "There are many factors due to of which people need to be careful about their education."? That's worse. "People need to be careful about their education, due to many factors." would be okay, albeit still a bit awkward, and not a correct usage of "due to" according to many prescriptivists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stimulating is not a synonym of various or numerous, so do not use it here.

To stimulate means to invoke a feeling or reaction in something.

Yes, it changes the whole meaning of the sentence. You would only use it in sentences like "This experience stimulates the senses", "This medicine stimulates the nervous system" or "This toy keeps the children stimulated."

"Various" or "numerous" are appropriate words to use here. You could also use "multiple", "a wide range", "a number", etc.

Comment: This is correct, but could you please add more detail why "simulating" is incorrect, and how it ought to be used?

Comment: I posted this to get the reputation required to comment, and the OP had a specific sentence which he wanted the answer for, so don't be too quick to criticise. Now that I have that reputation, yes I can add more detail.

Comment: "Stimulating" used in this sense (i.e., to describe factors in education that people need to be careful about) implies that there are factors that could make people inappropriately excited - perhaps even sexually excited.  I don't think that's the meaning the OP is intending to communicate.